# How to customized news container in website

Tags: javascript

I'm using code in an iFrame to embed news in a website. I am unable to customize the iFrame.

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com/uds/modules/elements/newsshow/iframe.html?topic=n,p,s,n&rsz=small" frameborder="0" width="728" height="90" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"></iframe>here
```

Comment: what are you trying to customize and what is going wrong? What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to customize content of iframe , its not possible in cross domain iframe. browsers not allow to access any DOM object of cross site. and if it is same domain then its possible. I think in your case its looking cross domain frame.

Answer (score 1):

You can customized the iframe itself (border width, color, etc.) but cannot change the contents of the source URL. I will note, however, that if the source URL did not set a background color, you can set the default content background color from the iframe using a CSS style statement.

BTW, do note that Google "newsshow" has been deprecated for a long time and now no longer works.

Here is a Google News RSS replacement that in many ways is better:

http://www.gooplusplus.com/news-frame-guide.html

See forum article here:

http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=26985